# how to import module in python using string

Tags: python, python-import

I have a string which contains the name of a library that I want to import. How can I import that library dynamically?

For example:

```
library = "mylibrary"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use python default function `__import__` to import modules.

```
mod = __import__(module)
```

but path of this module need to be appended in sys.path

```
sys.path.insert(0, <path of module>)
```

Comment: Best practice is to use `importlib`.